# Http Client registration based on http header received from a middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2, httpclient, httphandler

****I am having below situation : I am using web api core 3.1 framework (c#)****

I am using typed httpclient registered in the startup . while registering typed client on startup, i am not able to provide the base URL and credentials because I am getting thru a service called configread and it reads the data from the header , which will be only available when one of our middle ware runs and sets it.

in my case base address, user id and passwords are coming from a service call but service calls depends on the request header (httpContext object). in the configureService methods , request context is not available.

Right now i am having trouble to get the httpClient from the startup.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Update1:

I am adding a typed client as below

```
service.AddHttpClient<IAgencyServiceAgent,AgencyServiceAgent> (GetAgencyAgentHttpClient()).
ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(GetAgencyHttpMessageHandler()) private Action<HttpClient> GetAgencyAgentHttpClient () 
{ 
var configUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(ConfigConstants.CONFIGSERVICE URL) 
return httpClient => { 
// Here the base address is availble thru another service // which accept the data from the httpContext and based on the values / It pulls the base address and request header etc... 
} 
}
```

Update2:

I am having difficulty in setting this httpclient in the startup beacuse baseUrl and other info depends on the request object. For ex: i am reading a request header called DEV1 and passing it to another service , then it will return me the base address and credentials needed then after i can set the http client My questions are how do go about it . When httpClient configurations are depend on the httpContext object .. then how we should register and use it Thanks

Comment: According to your description, it is very hard to understand your issue. Could you please post more details related codes?

Comment: I am adding a typed client as below 

service.AddHttpClient<IAgencyServiceAgent,AgencyServiceAgent> 
(GetAgencyAgentHttpClient()).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(GetAgencyHttpMessageHandler())

private Action<HttpClient> GetAgencyAgentHttpClient ()
{
 var configUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(ConfigConstants.CONFIGSERVICE URL)  
return httpClient => {
     // Here the base address is availble thru another service 
     // which accept the  data from the  httpContext and based on the values
   / It pulls the base address and request header etc...
}

}

Comment: I am having difficulty in setting this httpclient in the startup beacuse baseUrl and other info depends on the request object.

For ex: i am reading a request header called DEV1 and passing it to another service , then it will return me the base address and credentials needed 
then after i can set the http client

My questions are how do go about it . When httpClient configurations are depend on the httpContext object .. then how we should register and use it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to build ServiceProvider inside your `GetAgencyAgentHttpClient` method and use GetService method to get which service you want to use.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
        services.AddHttpClient("hello", c =>
        {
            //Build service provider
            ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            //Get the ICurrentUserService
            var currentUserService = serviceProvider.GetService<ICurrentUserService>();
            //Use ICurrentUserService GetIPaddress method
            var re=  currentUserService.GetIPaddress();
            c.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000");
        }).AddTypedClient(c => Refit.RestService.For<IHelloClient>(c)); ;
```

Result:

[image]

---

If you want to check get the http header from current httprequest, you could try to get the httpcontext accessor in the service.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
        services.AddHttpClient("hello", c =>
        {
            ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            //var currentUserService = serviceProvider.GetService<ICurrentUserService>();
            //var re=  currentUserService.GetIPaddress();
            var httpcontext = serviceProvider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
             var re = httpcontext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.ToList();

            c.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000");
        }).AddTypedClient(c => Refit.RestService.For<IHelloClient>(c));
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here is my situation . i am able to build service providers but in order to get the base address , i need to pass the request header to my service  ,Request header is part of my httpContext . Which is not available here .  It is available only when middleware runs.. Can you please help . on how to proceed in this case..

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the http header in middleware? Maybe you could try to get it from httpcontext accssor?

Comment: Thanks … I think this might help me... I will try and let you know ...

Comment: I tried acessing the IHttpContextAccessor but it is coming null to me . unfortunately it does not work..

Comment: Could you please share your middleware to tell us which header you want to get inside the httpclient and where you will use this httpclient.

Comment: Thanks ....I have a middleware that reads the request header from the request object and based on header itcalls to the config service to get all the configuration. so inside middleware i am able to get the configuration values ... but  what i am trying here is to create httpClient in the configureService method which runs before the middleware. so is there a way configure httpClient after configureService method is called  and httpClient needs baseaddress that is only availble only when middleware is run ... not before ... so how to get httpClient in this case ...

Comment: Where you store the configuration? If you just read it, it couldn't pass to the other service to use it.

Comment: i store my configuration in config service ..its http based service present in spring cloud framwork

Comment: I really suggest you post your codes with us, without codes we couldn't understand how your application works.

Comment: DEV1:
   URL: 'http://myurl.com'
   userid: 
   password:

DEV2:
  URL: 'http://myurl.com'
   userid: 
   password:
   


When i pass DEV1  i got above URL , user id and password 
and DEV1 is only coming from header which i am reading thur middleware

How to configure httpClient in this situation ...